# Why trackBar2.Maximum show 16 steps and not 15?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

bitmaps is array and contain 15 indexs from 0 to 14.
But after setting trackBar2.Maximum to the bitmaps Length i see on the trackBar2 16 places not 15.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            trackBar2.Enabled = true;
            trackBar2.Maximum = bitmaps.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < bitmaps.Length; i++)
            {
               ConvertTo24(bitmaps[i]);
            }
            timer2.Stop();
            b1.Dispose();
        }
```

Then in the trackBar2 scroll event:

```
private void trackBar2_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadPictureAt(trackBar2.Value, sender);
            mymem = ToStream(bitmaps[trackBar2.Value], ImageFormat.Bmp);
            backTexture = TextureLoader.FromStream(D3Ddev, mymem);
            scannedCloudsTexture = new Texture(D3Ddev, 512, 512, 1, Usage.Dynamic, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default);
            timer1.Stop();
            Button1Code();
            timer1.Start();
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
```

When i move the scrollBar2 to the top it's throwing exception: Index was outside the bounds of the array

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException was caught
  HResult=-2146233080
  Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  Source=My Weather Station
  StackTrace:
       at mws.ScanningClouds.trackBar2_Scroll(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\ScanningClouds.cs:line 709
       at System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar.OnScroll(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(IntPtr hWnd, Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WmVScroll(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseMove(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at mws.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\Program.cs:line 28
  InnerException:
```

Line 709 is:

```
mymem = ToStream(bitmaps[trackBar2.Value], ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

The trackBar2 minimum is set to 0 i tried to set it to 1 but then i get the exception on the same line. Same exception even that now trackBar2 have 15 steps still same exception when i drag the trackBar2 scroller to the top to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TrackBar`'s `Minimum` & `Maximum` bounds are inclusive. Try setting `trackBar2.Maximum = bitmaps.Length - 1`

If you want a "friendly" GUI, it's better to set `.Minimum = 1` & `.Maximum = bitmaps.Length` and use its `Value` as `int pictureIndex = trackBar2.Value - 1;`